# Node.js JSON headers

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, routes

I'm toying with this node.js server-app that has routes both for a homemade REST API and for serving static pages. When it serves the static pages I get no errors, but when it serves stuff from my API, I get the following in console:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at SendStream.headersAlreadySent (C:\path_to_node_folder\node_modules\send\lib\send.js:302:13)
at SendStream.send (C:\path_to_node_folder\node_modules\express\node_modules\send\lib\send.js:490:17)
at C:\path_to_node_folder\node_modules\express\node_modules\send\lib\send.js:467:10
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

My routes:

```js
module.exports = function(app) {
  "use strict";

  app.get('/api', function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({
      message : 'Welcome to the Angular Blog RESTful API'
    });
    next();
  });

  app.get('/api/article/:permalink', function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({
      message   : "Article retrieved",
      permalink : req.params.permalink
    });
    next();
  });

  app.post('/api/comment', function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({
      message : "save comment"
    });
    next();
  });

  app.use(function(req, res) {
    // use res.sendfile, as it streams instead of reading the file into memory.
    res.sendfile('./public_html/index.html');
  });
};
```

Now, please don't hate on the returned JSON data, I am just messing around with it for now :)

**Question: How do I get rid of the above console-error?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call either `res.json()` or `next()`, but not both. Only call `next()` if you are implementing a middleware or if you want to forward an error to the error handler.

```
if (!req.query.userId) {
  return next(new Error('UserId is missing!'));
}
res.json({ message: "ok" });
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for the explanation :)